# Inherit existing web parts and override methods

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts

When developing web parts in SharePoint can I inherit from the existing web parts and override their methods?

Or do I always need to start from scratch.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they are not sealed, you can inherit from them. In practise, It might work or not depending on how the web part you want to extend.

Answer (score 0):

Most (all?) OTB parts are sealed.

A new toolbar with icon/no buttons sounds more like a design solution. Place the topnav placeholder in a invisible panel at the bottom (so page doesn't crash) and modify the rest visually (css+firebug) . Assuming I am not misunderstanding what you mean.

Its pretty easy to get started with webparts, http://blah.winsmarts.com//2006/05/14/writing-custom-webparts-for-sharepoint-2007.aspx should show you how. From there you should be able to write an RSS reader easily.